# I changed the URL

Tags: urls

I changed URL to whatismyipadress.com's result instead of localhost, and i can't access it anymore where's that edited to change it back?

I am using WAMP, if that helps.

It doesn't meet the quality standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL helped.
The answer must be at least 30 characters long.

Comment: The Codex is always the best first place to look. Then searching here is the second step. And the googles are always helpful....